# Error using Spotipy: spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_client, error_description: Invalid client

Tags: python, spotipy

I've been wanting to start a small spotify-based project and I'm currently trying to utilize python to create a playlist using the spotipy library as such:

```
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import spotipy.util as util


scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
username = 'aaronang_'

token = SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope,username=username)
spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager = token)


playlist_name = input("Enter a playlistname:")
playlist_description = input("Enter a playlist description:")

spotifyObject.user_playlist_create(user=username,name=playlist_name,public=True,description=playlist_description)
```

I set my client id,client secret and redirect uri in terminal's virtual environment(venv) yet using:

```
set CLIENT_ID=c3032b421ce94......9a05abcb623da
set CLIENT_SECRET=32a9c32611......5b69cf643f7c33e
set CLIENT_REDIRECT_URI=http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

I end up getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\spotifyPlaylist.py", line 17, in <module>
    spotifyObject.user_playlist_create(user=username,name=playlist_name,public=True,description=playlist_description)
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 784, in user_playlist_create
    return self._post("users/%s/playlists" % (user,), payload=data)
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 302, in _post
    return self._internal_call("POST", url, payload, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 221, in _internal_call
    headers = self._auth_headers()
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 212, in _auth_headers
    token = self.auth_manager.get_access_token(as_dict=False)
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 525, in get_access_token
    token_info = self.validate_token(self.cache_handler.get_cached_token())
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 380, in validate_token
    token_info = self.refresh_access_token(
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 596, in refresh_access_token
    self._handle_oauth_error(http_error)
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 146, in _handle_oauth_error
    raise SpotifyOauthError(
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_client, error_description: Invalid client
```

I've seen this code work for others, yet my token won't validate. I've got a token from https://developer.spotify.com/console/put-playlist-tracks/ which worked.

Thanks.

Comment: did you get token from documentation? It may not work. You should login to acocunt on this page, generate own API KEY and use it.

Comment: I think it should be `SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID` `SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET` `SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI`. You may also check in code if they are avaliable `os.getenv("SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID")` - this gives my CLIENT ID for SPOTIPY.

Comment: see documentation for [Spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#quick-start) - it uses `SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID`, `SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET`, `SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI`

Comment: I realized it my mistake using SPOTIPY instead of client id yet I still get the same error, I'll try it again and let you know what happens

Comment: So I ran set to get my env variables that I set this what it shows:SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID=c3032b421ce9...........0b9a05abcb623da
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET=32a9c32611d......5b69cf643f7c33e
SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_UI=http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Comment: did you run `os.getenv("SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID")` to check if Python see these values?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `.cache`, this is where the tokens are stored and spotipy will try using them, even though they are invalid. After deletion, the authentication window should reappear when using

```
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager, auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, scope=scope, redirect_uri=redirect_uri))
```